# Pip install actually IN a docker container (Airflow)

Tags: docker, pip, airflow

I am really new with docker. I have it run now for airflow. For one of the airflow DAGs, I perform `python jobs.<job_name>.run` which is located on the server + within the docker. However, this python code needs packages to run and I am having trouble installing those.

If I put in the Dockerfile a `RUN pip install ...` it doesn't seem to work. If I go 'in' the docker container by `docker exec -ti <name_of_worker> bash` and I perform `pip freeze`, no packages show up.

However, if I perform the pip install command while I am in the worker, the airflow DAG will run successfully. However, I  shouldn't have to perform this task every time I rebuild my containers. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Might be obvious, but did you rebuild and re-deploy the image? Could you show us the Dockerfile?

Comment: Good comment, but yes I did rebuild en redeploy. So in the docker file it does pip install for packages airflow need (so in a DAG, it uses pyspark) and that works. However when I want to run the python script outside of the DAG with `python jobs.<job_name>.run` it doesn't see those packages anymore.

Comment: In your dockerfile is airflow being installed as a particular user and/or is it running within a python virtual environment?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this? How can I look this up?

Comment: Can you post the docker file. Seems the airflow and the packages are installed in a different python virtual environment or user.